# Text inside container was overflow when minimize screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a container with width `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.75`.When I minimize screen size text inside the container is overflowing.

This is the output I got now:

[image]

```
class ProfileTopPortion extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfileTopPortion({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.75,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Color(0xffEBEBEB), width: 0.4),
                color: Color(0xfffbfbfa),
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                    child: MouseRegion(
                      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            //  Get.toNamed('/events',arguments: 0);
                          },
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                              allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                              Images.avatar,
                            ),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'First Name',
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 6,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Engineer',
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Email',
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Organization',
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 30,
                          ),
                          Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'testEmail1235@gmail.com',
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              Text("Test12346@gma.com"),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 25,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried flexible and expanded widgets but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Expanded` in `two` widget, try this:

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.75,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Color(0xffEBEBEB), width: 0.4),
            color: Color(0xfffbfbfa),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                child: MouseRegion(
                  cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        //  Get.toNamed('/events',arguments: 0);
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                             allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                             Images.avatar,
                          ),
                         )),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              Expanded(//<---- add this
                child: Column(
                  // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'First Name',
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 6,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Engineer',
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Email',
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Organization',
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                        Expanded(//<---- add this
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'testEmail1235@gmail.com',
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,//<---- add this
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Test12346@gma.com",
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,//<---- add this
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 25,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap this column to expanded and also wrap the inner texts into flexible

```
Expanded( child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Flexible(child:Text(
                                'testEmail1235@gmail.com',
                              )),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              Flexible(child:Text("Test12346@gma.com")),
                            ],
                          ),)
```

Answer (score 0):

---

> Wrap your text with FittedBox

---

```
FittedBox(
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      "your text",
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using height and width for container you can use the constraints property i.e

```
    constraints:Boxconstrains(
maxWidth:double.infinity,
maxHeight:double.infinity,

),
```

It will resize the container height and width according to the text inside.
You can use padding for further decoration

Comment: As per my requirement, the width of the container box should be the MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.75

Comment: So instead of giving width to the container you can adjust the font size